# How do I change the 'modified' timestamp of a file in Windows using a batch file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

How do I change the 'modified' timestamp of a file in Windows using a batch file?

Comment: Which one? Do you want to touch the file? Or the creation date?

Comment: Touch it. Will edit question to make that clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows version of the Unix touch command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432089/touch-file-to-update-the-date-time-of-file-modified-date-windowsxp-batchscrip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have cygwin, or git for Windows, installed and on the PATH you can use the `touch` command:

`touch -d "date and time" filename`

(omit the -d flag to use the current date and time.)

Alternatively, see the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command