# Touch file to update the date/time of file? (Modified Date) (WindowsXP BatchScript)

Tags: file, datetime, batch-file

What's a batch script command to touch on a file to update its date and time to the current date and time? (Modified Date)

For example, Joe Blow sends me a text document which he created months ago, when he emails me the document, I want to keep track of how old it is from the day I received it (not when he created it) so I want to update the file's date/time to the current date/time.

I have a batch script to automatically weed out files that haven't been edited within 90 days, so this is troublesome when I receive a particularly older file then all of a sudden it disappears.

And I need it via a batch script as I have hundreds of files to manage, and it's for archiving files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows version of the Unix touch command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't take all the credit, but I did look through my todo.txt to find it

[Microsoft "touch"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69581) it's a KB article from like 5 years ago

The jist of it is you use `copy /b MYFILENAME +,,` where MYFILENAME is your file

Comment: And just to ensure the correctness of this, when using long file names, would it be [ "C:\Documents and Settings\User\file.txt" +,, ] or [ "C:\Documents and Settings\User\file.txt +,," ]?

Answer (score 3):

This is an expansion on aflat's anwer.

1) Microsoft support provides an explanation and simple touch.bat script.
2) My custom touch.cmd, which expands on the MS script by including "touch /?" help text.
3) My custom midastouch.cmd, which provides several options including recursive operation and date operations.

As aflat wrote, the simple answer is:

```
copy /b FILENAME +,,
```

As you might expect, FILENAME can include relative or absolute path and wildcards like *.txt.

**1. Microsoft[1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69581)** support:

> The following MS-DOS command updates the date and time stamps of a
>   file named "EXAMPLE" without altering the contents of the file. This
>   is similar to the TOUCH utility found in XENIX and in some third-party
>   MS-DOS toolkits.

```
COPY /B EXAMPLE +,,
```

> The COPY command can concatenate a file onto an existing file when
>   used in the form:

```
COPY FILE1+FILE2
```

> In this example, the contents of FILE2 are appended to FILE1, leaving FILE2 unchanged. When copying in this mode, the COPY command
>   switches to ASCII mode where the ^Z (0x01A) end-of-file marker is
>   honored.
>
> Therefore, with the above command, the /b forces the COPY command into
>   binary mode, the filename is the file to be updated, the + (plus sign)
>   indicates that a file is to be appended, and the ,, (commas) are
>   placeholders for the remaining parameters (which are not included in
>   this example). Because the file to be appended is not specified, the
>   COPY command will append nothing and only update the time and date
>   stamps for the file.
>
> The following batch file, TOUCH.BAT, can be used to automate the
>   process:

```
@echo off    
if %1.==. goto end    
if not exist %1 goto end    
copy /b %1 +,, > nul    
echo %1 touched!    
:end
```

> This batch file requires one parameter, the file to be "touched." If the
>   parameter is not supplied, line 2 will cause the batch file to
>   exit without doing anything. If the specified file does not exist,
>   line 3 will cause the batch file to exit also.

**2. Touch.cmd**

```
@echo off
:: -----------------------------------------
:: Process input parameter
:: -----------------------------------------

: Help requestes?
if "%1%"=="/?" goto help
if "%1%"=="?" goto help
if "%1%"=="" goto help

:: -----------------------------------------
:: Update Modified Date property to now
:: -----------------------------------------
if not exist %1% goto end    
copy /b %1% +,, > nul    
echo %1 touched!    
goto end

:help

@echo off
echo :: --------------------------------------------------------------
echo :: Touch.cmd Help
echo :: --------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Touch.cmd is batch script to update the Modified Date property 
echo of teh specified file to the current
echo date and time.  
echo.
echo Syntax: touch filename
echo         where,
echo         filename is the name of the name of the file to "touch."
echo         filename may include a relative o full path.
echo         filename may include wild cards like *.txt.
echo.

:end
```

**3. MidasTouch.cmd**

```
@echo off
:: -----------------------------------------
:: Find files older than specified date
:: -----------------------------------------

:: -----------------------------------------
:: Default Values
:: -----------------------------------------
set "default_path=%cd%"
set "default_err_log=%cd%\midastouch_err.log"
set /a default_date=-365
set "open_log=False"
set "recurse=True"

:: -----------------------------------------
:: Process input parameters 
:: -----------------------------------------

: Help requestes?
if "%1%"=="/?" goto help
if "%1%"=="?" goto help
if /I "%1%"=="help" goto help

set "dir_in="
set "err_log="
set "dd="

:: Read in commandline arguements.
echo Arguements:
:arguement_loop
    if "%1%"=="/p" (
        echo     Path: %2%
        set dir_in=%2%
        shift
        goto loop_bottom)
    if "%1%"=="/l" (
        echo     Error log: %2%
        set err_log=%2%
        shift
        goto loop_bottom)    
    if "%1%"=="/-l" (
        echo     No error log.  Output to console.
        set err_log=CON
        shift
        goto loop_bottom)    
    if "%1%"=="/d" (
        echo     Date: %2%
        set /a dd=%2% 
        shift
        goto loop_bottom)
    if "%1%"=="/o" (
        echo     Open log: True
        set "open_log=True"
        goto loop_bottom)
    if "%1%"=="/-o" (
        echo     Open log: False
        set "open_log=False"
        goto loop_bottom)
    if "%1%"=="/s" (
        echo     Recursive: True
        set "recurse=True"
        goto loop_bottom)
    if "%1%"=="/-s" (
        echo     Recursive: False
        set "recurse=False"
        goto loop_bottom)
    if not "%1%"=="" (
        if "%dir_in%"=="" (
            echo     Path: %1%
            set dir_in=%1%
            goto loop_bottom)
        if "%err_log%"=="" (
            echo     Error log: %1%
            set err_log=%1%
            goto loop_bottom)
        if "%dd%"=="" (
            echo     Date: %1%
            set /a dd=%1%
            goto loop_bottom)
    )
:loop_bottom
shift
if not "%1%"=="" goto arguement_loop

if "%dir_in%"=="" ( 
    set dir_in=%default_path%)
if "%err_log%"=="" ( 
    set err_log=%default_err_log%)
if "%dd%"=="" ( 
    set /a dd=%default_date%)

:: -----------------------------------------
:: Execution
:: -----------------------------------------

:: Write header
set "header=Touch_dir.cmd Error Log"
if exist %err_log% (
    del /q %err_log%)
@echo %header% >%err_log%

set cmd_str="cmd /c copy /b @path +,,"

:: Update Modified Date property to now
if /I "%recurse%"=="True" (
    set cmd_str=forfiles /s /p %dir_in% /d %dd% /c %cmd_str%
) else (
    set cmd_str=forfiles /p %dir_in% /d %dd% /c %cmd_str%
)
echo Command: %cmd_str% >>%err_log%
echo Errors: >>%err_log%
echo. >>%err_log%
echo Executing command: %cmd_str%
@echo Updating Modified Date of files older than date: %dd%.
@echo This may take a while.  Please be patient...
@echo.
echo.
set cmd_str=%cmd_str% || @echo Failed to update: @path >>%err_log%"
%cmd_str%

:: Results
@echo Error log: %err_log% 
if "%open_log%"=="True" (start %err_log%)

goto end

:help
@echo off
echo :: --------------------------------------------------------------
echo :: Touch_dir.cmd Help
echo :: --------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Touch.cmd is batch script to recursively "touch" all files in a
echo folder to update their Modified Date property to the current
echo date and time.  
echo.
echo Syntax: touch_dir /d directory /l err_log /m months
echo         where,
echo         /p  path       Path containing files with Modified
echo                        Date values to update to now.
echo                        (default = current directory).
echo         /s  (or /-s)   Recursive (or not recursive) search 
echo                        (default recursive is %recurse%).
echo         /l  err_log    Error log: list of files not updated
echo                        (default err_log: midastouch_err.log).
echo         /o  (or /-o)   Open (or do not open) error log after 
echo                        execution (default open_log: %open_log%).
echo         /d  date       Selects files with a last modified date greater
echo                        than or equal to (+), or less than or equal to
echo                        (-), the specified date using the
echo                        "MM/dd/yyyy" format; or selects files with a
echo                        last modified date greater than or equal to (+)
echo                        the current date plus "dd" days, or less than or
echo                        equal to (-) the current date minus "dd" days. A
echo                        valid "dd" number of days can be any number in
echo                        the range of 0 - 32768.
echo                        "+" is taken as default sign if not specified.
echo                        (default date is: %default_date%).
echo.

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that the same source provide a batch script.

```vb
@echo off
goto start

:usage
echo usage: TOUCH.BAT "MYFILENAME"
exit /b 0

:start
if %1.==. goto usage
if not exist %1 goto usage
copy /b %1 +,, > nul
echo %1 touched!
exit /b 0
```