# Batch file to update all files Modified and Accessed Date and Time

Tags: batch-file, dos

Is it possible to write a batch file which will update the Modified and Accessed Date/Times to today's date? I need to do this to all files in a directory every night in a scheduled task.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the 'modified' timestamp of a file in Windows using a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686007/how-do-i-change-the-modified-timestamp-of-a-file-in-windows-using-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

```
cd c:\MyFolder
copy c:\MyFolder,,+
```